# SuccessCallback firing immediately in Xrm.Page.data.save

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am writing javascript code to change the form of a entity in Dynamics CRM based on the value of a field on each form.

To change the form, the user has to change the value of the field. 
Then during the onChange event, my js comes in, triggers saving, has to wait for the result and then change the form. (If you save and change at the same time, there is still a window shown asking the user to confirm leaving unsaved changes)

Now there should be a way to do that:

```
Xrm.Page.data.save(saveOptions).then(successCallback, errorCallback)
```

as it is described on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn481607(v=crm.6).aspx):

> Saves the record asynchronously with the option to set callback functions to be executed after the save operation is completed.

I am using it as such:

```
var campaignType = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('typecode').getValue();
if (xxx.Forms.hasOwnProperty(campaignType)) {
Xrm.Page.data.save().then(function () { xxx.redirectToForm(xxx.Forms[campaignType]); }, null);
```

But the form change is still triggered immediately during the save.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am using Crm 2013, sorry the msdn link was pointing to the wrong url, fixed it

Comment: You can set the setSubmitedMode of that field to never, so if it is changed if will not ask to save the changes. However you won't update this field, so you could update this field with a Request before saving the form.

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar problem while trying to update the process bar.

```
Xrm.Page.data.save().then
        (function () {
                window.location.reload(true);
            },
            function () {
                windows.alert("broken");
            }    
        );
```

I strongly suggest you to try to apply the logic on a vanilla CRM, for me what was breaking the logic was a third party component called N52 Rules, their code was interfering with the callback forcing the refresh of the page before the save event. Your code seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

Hey the Save and Refresh Calls are Asynchronous! that is why it hits the success handler immediately.

What you can try is using SDK.REST.js file for CRM

```
function updateFunction(entityId) {

     var campaignType = Xrm.Page.getAttribute('typecode').getValue();
     if (xxx.Forms.hasOwnProperty(campaignType)) {
     var entity= {};
     entity.typecode= campaignType;

     SDK.REST.updateRecord(
         entityId,
         entity,
         entityName, //"Account"
         function () {
          writeMessage("The record changes were saved");
          xxx.redirectToForm(xxx.Forms[campaignType]);
         },
         null
       );
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334427(v=crm.7).aspx

Here you can call `updateFunction` given above `onChange` and in the `onSuccess` handler you can try calling the form you want to call. I haven't tried it the way you want, but let me know if it works.

check this link out as well

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334720.aspx#BKMK_entityOnSave